# Parameter is not valid Exception in windowsForm

Tags: c#, exception

i am using multi panels for making multi section project and using access database and inserting some thing in it like below:

```
    private void addmoneyPanel_firstLoad()
    {
        try
        {
            employee_list.Items.Clear();
            connection.Open();
            OleDbCommand command = new OleDbCommand();
            command.Connection = connection;

            command.CommandText = "select Ename,Elastname from employee";
            OleDbDataReader reader = command.ExecuteReader();
            while(reader.Read())
            {
                employee_list.Items.Add(reader[0].ToString() + " \n" +reader[1].ToString());
            }
            connection.Close();
            /*addMoneyPanelMes.Text = "با موفقیت ذخیره شد.";
            addMoneyPanelMes.ForeColor = Color.Green;*/

        }
        catch (Exception err)
        {
            addMoneyPanelMes.Text = "خظا در ارتباط با پایگاه داده.";
            addMoneyPanelMes.ForeColor = Color.Red;
            addMoneyPanelMes.Visible = true;
        }
    }
    private void pictureBox1_Click_1(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        try
        {
            string TempPrice, TempCheckNum, TempCriditNum;
            connection.Open();
            OleDbCommand command = new OleDbCommand();
            command.Connection = connection;
            if(radioButton1.Checked == true)
            {
                TempPrice = money_price.Text;
                TempCheckNum = "0";
                TempCriditNum = "0";
            }else if(radioButton2.Checked == true)
            {
                TempPrice = money_price.Text;
                TempCheckNum = "0";
                TempCriditNum = criditNumber.Text;
            }
            else
            {
                TempPrice = money_price.Text;
                TempCheckNum = checkNumber.Text;
                TempCriditNum = "0";
            }
            ///////////////////////////////split the combo box names
            string mainToSplit,id = "";
            string[] splited;
            mainToSplit = employee_list.SelectedItem.ToString();
            splited = mainToSplit.Split('\n');
            splited[0] = "" + splited[0].Remove((splited[0].Length-1),1);

            command.CommandText = "select id from employee where Ename='" +splited[0]+ "' AND Elastname='" +splited[1]+"'";
            OleDbDataReader reader = command.ExecuteReader();
            if (reader.Read())
                id = reader[0].ToString();


            connection.Close();

            connection.Open();
            OleDbCommand command2 = new OleDbCommand();

            command2.Connection = connection;
            command2.CommandText = "INSERT INTO realMoney (price,cardnum,checknum,theDate,employeeid,descrip) values(" + Int32.Parse(TempPrice) + "," + Int32.Parse(TempCriditNum) + "," + Int32.Parse(TempCheckNum) + ",#" + dateTimePickerX1.GetSelectedDateInPersianDateTime().ToShortDateString() + "#," + Int32.Parse(id) + ",'" + money_descrip.Text + "')";
            command2.ExecuteNonQuery();
            connection.Close();
            addMoneyPanelMes.Text = "با موفقیت ذخیره شد.";
            addMoneyPanelMes.ForeColor = Color.Green;
            addMoneyPanelMes.Visible = true;

        }

        catch(OleDbException h)
        {
            addMoneyPanelMes.Text = "خظا در ارتباط با پایگاه داده.";
            addMoneyPanelMes.ForeColor = Color.Red;
            addMoneyPanelMes.Visible = true;
        }
    }
```

this 2 function will be run successfully but after that i will get the "Parameter is not valid" Exception in this part:

```
   private void timer1_Tick(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if(pass == 0 || pass == 1)
        {
            prossespass();
        }
        DateTime datetime = DateTime.Now;
        try
        {
            time.Text = string.Format("{0:hh:mm:ss}", DateTime.Now); // error here
            timesun.Text = datetime.ToString("tt");
        }
        catch(Exception d)
        { }

    }
```

this is a timer for a clock in my project. so after returning to the main panel that clock is existing in it (make the main panel visible and hide current panel) clock text box cant set and my project crashed.
i dont know what the problem is.
but if i erase this part from the second function that i mentioned:

```
  addMoneyPanelMes.Text = "با موفقیت ذخیره شد.";
            addMoneyPanelMes.ForeColor = Color.Green;
            addMoneyPanelMes.Visible = true;
```

or removing insert section in second function above:

```
connection.Open();
            OleDbCommand command2 = new OleDbCommand();

            command2.Connection = connection;
            command2.CommandText = "INSERT INTO realMoney (price,cardnum,checknum,theDate,employeeid,descrip) values(" + Int32.Parse(TempPrice) + "," + Int32.Parse(TempCriditNum) + "," + Int32.Parse(TempCheckNum) + ",#" + dateTimePickerX1.GetSelectedDateInPersianDateTime().ToShortDateString() + "#," + Int32.Parse(id) + ",'" + money_descrip.Text + "')";
            command2.ExecuteNonQuery();
            connection.Close();
```

i have other function in other panels that work with database but work great together this is it. thanks for your help.

Comment: Please learn to use [parameterized queries](http://blog.codinghorror.com/give-me-parameterized-sql-or-give-me-death/). This kind of string concatenations are open for [SQL Injection](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SQL_injection) attacks.

Comment: this is a personal application and i am not afraid of injection. but thanks for ur replaying

Comment: The line in question doesn't throw anything here. But to test really we need to know what is your locale?

Comment: @sajjad.rezaee: even if you are currently not afraid, that might change in future if you don't stop using unsafe code. Actually it's pretty easy to use sql-parameters and it also avoids some localization or performance issues.

Comment: Another thing not correct is the empty try/catch. How do you know the correct line and message if you have swallowed the exception?

Comment: Can you show us the full exception?

Comment: @Steve i debug the program so its how i find out the messages

Comment: thanks guys i find out the problem

Answer (score 0):

just turn the timer off:

```
timer1.Enabled = false;
```

when  enter to each panel and turn it on when come back to main panel:

```
timer1.Enabled = true;
```